# How to limit MySQL query result to specific results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a news table in MySQL Database I query the table and show the title of the news in one PHP pages but now the table getting bigger so I want to divide the results into pages I mean to show each 50 news title in one page (pagenation).
I use this query to bring the news :

```
SELECT news.*, categories.category, users.username 
FROM news INNER JOIN 
     users on news.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN 
     categories on categories.id = news.category_id 
order by news.timestamp DESC 
limit $min,$max
```

and this is part of the PHP page (How I calculate the max and min)

```
$news_per_page = 50;
if(!empty($_GET['p_n']))
{
    $p_n = $_GET['p_n'];
    $max = $news_per_page*$p_n; 
    $min = ($max - $news_per_page); 
}
else
{
    $p_n = 1;
    $max = 50; 
    $min = 0;
}
$news = all_news($max,$min);
```

The sql giving me wrong result when i pass the limits I do not know why. Is it wrong to specify the max and min of sql query by this way?? Should I correct something in this code?

Comment: The LIMIT clause is explained in the Mysql manual, it also shows your form, so it says what the first and the second parameter for LIMIT stands for. `$max` is wrong in your case, it's always the number per page, so constant, so 50 in your case. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got problems handling pagination properly, I suggest you use some code that is working, for example a pagination class that takes three parameters:

1. The current page.
2. The total count.
3. The number of items per page.

And then that class will generate the `LIMIT` clause for you. Example:

```
$pageNumber = 1;
$totalCount = 17;
$perPage    = 5;

$pagination = new LimitPagination($pageNumber, $totalCount, $perPage);
echo $pagination, "\n";
```

This would output

```
LIMIT 0, 5
```

because you'er on the first page. Such a class then could also filter out those problems you have here, for example setting to a negative page - just automatically. And also it can provide a lot of extra data, like the next and previous page, the current page, the number of total pages, if it is the first or the last page and what not:

```
$pagination->setPage(-2);
echo $pagination, "\n";
echo "Current: ",    $pagination->getPage(),
     "; Total: ",    $pagination->getTotalPages(),
     "; Previous: ", $pagination->getPreviousPage(),
     "; Next: ",     $pagination->getNextPage(), 
     "\n";
```

Output:

```
LIMIT 0, 5
Current: 1; Total: 4; Previous: 1; Next: 2
```

This is then easy to integrate with different code, including yours:

```
$pagination = new LimitPagination($_GET['p_n'], $totalCount, 50);
$limit = sprintf("%d, %d", $pagination->getOffset(), $pagination->getCount());
```

This should easily do it. Class is here as Gist: https://gist.github.com/4469154

Comment: Thank you very much for referring to this class it was so helpful

Answer (score 2):

The `LIMIT` clause, as explained in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), takes arguments **offset** and **count**. So if you want to get, for example, results from 201 to 250, you would use `LIMIT 200, 50`. Start by renaming your variables `$min` and `$max` to `$offset` and `$count`, and from there everything will fall into place.

Pseudocode:

```
offset = (requestedPageNumber - 1) * rowsPerPage;
count = rowsPerPage;
```

PHP Code:
(assuming page number is 0-based)

```
$rowsPerPage  = 50;
$page = empty($_GET['p_n']) ? 0 : $_GET['p_n'];
$offset  = $rowsPerPage * (int) $page;
$news = all_news($offset, $rowsPerPage);
```

Comment: Thank you for this information about the `$offset` and `$count` it was a big problem to me but now I can understand the whole thing thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set start (this you can achieve by using current page and per page property) and the second information is how many results you want (again per page property).

```
LIMIT . ($p_n - 1) * $news_per_page .', ' . $news_per_page
```

So, in your script it will be:

```
if(!empty($_GET['p_n']))
{
    // You need to protect your variables for SQL injection. For numbers (int) or integer() function it is enough.
    $p_n = (int) $_GET['p_n'];
    $max = (int) $news_per_page; 
    $min = (int) ($p_n - 1) * $news_per_page; 
}
else
{
    $p_n = 1;
    $max = 50; 
    $min = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
$news_per_page = 50;
if(!empty($_GET['p_n']))
{
   $p_n = intval($_GET['p_n']);
   $min = ($p_n-1) * $news_per_page;
   $max = $news_per_page;
}
else
{
   $p_n = 1;
   $max = 50; 
   $min = 0;
}
$news = all_news($max,$min);
```

While $_GET['p_n'] is page_number you dont' need to make any multiplies

Comment: -1: A bit complicated for that code. Could be written much smaller.

Comment: It was not about code complication and optimization but just making it work

Comment: Well, answers are about being helpful. Don't think it's that helpful w/o explaining why that code should be correct. And I'm not talking much about complication or optimization. Perhaps just setting $max to 50, and min to the get param multiplied then.

Comment: True, but I think the most important is quick answer to the question. I can write that max and min variables are not the best names, that in SQL query aliases may be used but it will not help the user at all